# Getting Files in a directory without sorting

Tags: c#

the code below will give the files in a directory as sorted array ! how can I ban that from sorting :

```
string sorted_files[]=  System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\A\\B\\");
```

For example it gives me:

```
01.txt
10.txt
11.txt
110.txt
2.txt
.
.
.
```

Comment: What order do you expect it in then? Do you need it shuffled for some reason? I suspect that is just giving it to you in the order that the operating system presents by default...

Comment: well what order did you expect the files to be in?

Comment: Why do you want them to not come in based on the already sorted string[] array..???

Comment: there is no concept of "no sorting" of files and directories... as soon as you try to enumerate over a seemingly random pile of things, you have to consider in which order you want to do that in. Maybe you want to show them in random order, or ordered by size or creation date?

Answer (score 4):

The ordering is already not guaranteed. From the docs of [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx):

> The order of the returned file names is not guaranteed; use the Sort() method if a specific sort order is required.

If the file system happens to give it to you in lexicographic order, that's fine - but you shouldn't assume it will... and if you want some other order, including "shuffled", you should implement that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Following the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx):

> The order of the returned file names is not guaranteed; use the Sort
>   method if a specific sort order is required.

Order is a pretty relative thing, it depends on a sorting criteria. So please find out which sorting criteria do you expect and then task would be more clear and achievable.